# How is it possible to give visitors option to refuse cookies?

Tags: cookies

I have visitors from EU, and i want to know if it possible to give visitors option to refuse cookies?
I have blog in blogger, how can I do it?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can add a script tag that will always delete all the cookies from your blog if they have not agree with it. Once they agree, you check the cookies saved in their browser, then use that condition to prevent your script that automatically delete all cookies.

Note : I have not try to implement this yet, but technically it's possible